# NiodeJS/ How to find size of an externally hosted image without downloading it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I need to find the sizes/metadata of externally hosted images in a document (e.g., markdown documents that have image tags in it), but need to do it without actually downloading the image.

Is there any way to do this easily on NodeJS/ExpressJs using javascript? Some of the solutions are many years old and not sure if there are better methods now.

Comment: Encode the content to base64 and then calculate the binary size? 
I'm not a nodeJs fan but maybe you got a slight idea of what i'm talking about?

Comment: @AdnaneAr I don't want to download the image on to my server - that's the issue. I'd like to just "inspect" its metadata and find its size.

Comment: Maybe try HEAD http method?

Comment: why would you use express?  are you hosting and want to expose the size of the image?  or fetching but only want the size, not the entire file?

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis it's a web app that does some operations that involve users uploading markdown files and generating docs on the server. But before I generate, I need to check the sizes of any externally referred images  and fail the ops if they exceed certain limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what was suggested in comments by only grabbing the `HEAD` instead of using a `GET` when you call the image.

Using [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) or whatever you like (http, axios, etc) you set the `method` to `HEAD` and look for `content-length`.

My example program that grabs a twitter favicon, headers only, looks like this:

```
const got = require('got');
(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await got('https://abs.twimg.com/favicons/twitter.ico', { method: 'HEAD' });
    console.log(response.headers);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('something is broken. that would be a new and different question.');
  }
})();
```

and in the response I see the line I need:

```
  'content-length': '912'
```

If the server doesn't respect `HEAD` or doesn't return a `content-length` header, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.